# How to enable RNDIS gadget on u-boot

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, u-boot

I am using stm32mp157c-dk2 board and I added the RNDIS gadget to the config file. When I run u-boot on the board I get "No ethernet found". This is the log of the boot:

```
U-Boot SPL 2018.11-stm32mp-r2.1-00026-g161ca183f1-dirty (Jan 31 2020 - 12:34:38 +0200)
Model: STMicroelectronics STM32MP157C-DK2 Discovery Board
RAM: DDR3-1066/888 bin G 1x4Gb 533MHz v1.41
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2018.11-stm32mp-r2.1-00026-g161ca183f1-dirty (Jan 31 2020 - 12:34:38 +0200)

CPU: STM32MP157CAC Rev.B
Model: STMicroelectronics STM32MP157C-DK2 Discovery Board
Board: stm32mp1 in basic mode (st,stm32mp157c-dk2)
Board: MB1272 Var2 Rev.C-01
DRAM:  512 MiB
Clocks:
- MPU : 650 MHz
- MCU : 208.878 MHz
- AXI : 266.500 MHz
- PER : 24 MHz
- DDR : 533 MHz

*******************************************
*   WARNING 500mA power supply detected   *
* Current too low, use a 3A power supply! *
*******************************************

NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   STM32 SDMMC2: 0, STM32 SDMMC2: 1
Loading Environment from EXT4... OK
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   No ethernet found.
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Boot over mmc0!
```

Do you have any suggestions? thanks for helpers!

Answer (score 0):

That big warning about too small of a power supply is the first thing to look at.  A lack of power tends to lead to not all blocks of the SoC being used / available.

Comment: I disabled the adc driver and removed the warning, still no change. In addition the mass storage gadget works with ums command. :(

Comment: How about giving it a better power supply?